# Can QR decomposition be used for matrix inversion?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

1. Is there any simple algorithm for matrix inversion (that can be implemented using C/C++)?
2. Can QR decomposition be used for matrix inversion? How?

Comment: The first question might be more suitable for [scicomp.SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 17):

[Gauss–Jordan elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Jordan_elimination) can be used for matrix inversion.

A QR-decomposition can certainly be used for matrix inversion because if $A=QR$ then $A^{-1} = R^{-1} Q^{-1} = R^{-1} Q^{T}$ and $R^{-1}$ is easy to compute because $R$ is triangular.

But consider *why* you need to invert a matrix. In most cases, you *don't*: you just need to solve a linear system $Ax=b$. If $A=QR$ then this system is equivalent to $Rx = Q^T b$, which is easy to solve because $R$ is triangular.

Comment: Thanks much for this useful answer. Could you elaborate on "$R^{-1}$ is easy to compute because $R$ is triangular"? How is a triangular matrix easily inverted?

Comment: @YanRaf, yes, I meant back-/foward-substitution.

Comment: @Peter: Huh? QR is not an eigenvalue-revealing decomposition (maybe you were thinking about the Schur decomposition?)

Comment: In any event: if one is using Gaussian elimination, some form of pivoting (partial, complete, or rook) is a must. With QR decomposition, one has a choice of (modified) Gram-Schmidt or Householder. If one takes the Householder route, one does not even need to explicitly form the orthogonal factor $\mathbf Q$ of $\mathbf A$ for solving $\mathbf A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$.